# Class inheriting from UITextField that makes it impossible to get the content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

for an SDK, I would like to create a text field class that behaves like a standard UITextField except that it is impossible for the developer using the SDK to know the value of the field (for security reasons). Is this possible?

My approach: When creating a `UISecureTextField` that inherits from `UITextField`, I can overload `text` and the notification delegates, but am I missing something? Is there still a way for the developer to access the field? Would you do something differently?

Comment: Maybe make sure attributedText isn't giving any info either

Answer (score 1):

Instead of blacklisting certain methods, you could go the opposite route – use containment so your `UISecureTextField` has a `UITextField` private property, and then whitelist the methods and properties you want to expose by calling through to the text field.

More work to maintain, but it's another way to do it!